# Create a chart with a particular horizontal bar in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, charts, bar-chart, achartengine

i asked one month ago if it's possible to make Gantt charts with an open source library on Android. Anyone helped me, so now i'm trying to create a similar graph.
I receive the data from a database  and i have to put this data in one graph.

I have to create where:
-In the x-axis i have the time expressed in hours:minutes
-In the y-axis i have the activities and i want that the graph can show when one activity is happened (for example activity1 from 07.58 to 08.02, from 14.04 to 15.01; activity2 from 12.00 to 13.25)

Gantt would be perfect, but there isn't a chart library on android for that.
A solution can be: If an activity happens, i draw a horizontal bar in the exact time when it happens. So if the activity happens for more seconds, i draw an unique horizontal bar.
Then i can use different colors for the activities to diversify them.

It's possible to create this chart with Achartengine or Afreechart?

Answer (score 1):

In AChartEngine, you can just add an extra line chart series for the vertical line.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried this way but did not have success. Can you give me a short example to do that?

Comment: Sorry but in my question i wrote "i draw a vertical bar in the exact time when it happens" but it is i draw a horizontal bar in the exact time when it happens"...the problem is that i can't(or i don't know how) draw an horizontal bar with not continous values (like a bar of a gantt chart)